# How to move google search bar to bottom of home screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, motorola, search

I have moto g4 plus rooted phone with Xposed installed. Google search bar is at the top of screen and it is inconvenient to reach it every time to search for apps.

Is there a way to move it to the bottom of the screen? I found several ways to remove google search bar but didn't find a way to move it. I don't want to use any third party launchers.

Comment: Which launcher are you using ? Generally, you should be able to drag search bar in all launchers.

Comment: I am not using any launcher. Just the default launcher of stock android.

Comment: That thing is merely a widget. So, you can drag to the bottom.

Comment: I also thought same way. Unfortunately, dragging is not working.

Comment: Then try it remove and then add again.

Comment: Google search bar doesnt appear to be a widget. There is no search bar widget in widget list. Also there is no option to remove. To remove that we have to use xposed modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46278/discussion-between-chillaranand-and-vivek-ji).